# How to operate a local branch in git

Tags: git

From here, http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/git, I think 
I can recreate a branch in my local repository by

```
$ git branch mytestbranch
<then I can may changes as my experimental>
```

My question is how can

- I forget all the changes I made in the 'mytestbranch' branch? and switch back to my original 's stage/version of my repository?
- I keep the changes I made and move every thing to my 'main' branch?

Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify your situation: it sounds like there is a remote repository, there is a branch (let's call it foo) in that remote repository, and you have used `git clone` to make a local repo that mirrors that remote repo. You see a branch named origin/foo, but you want a branch named foo that you can work on. Is that correct?

Comment: When I started using git, I found it really helpful to run `gitk --all` to see what was actually going on in the commits and branches in a graphical fashion.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to forget everything that you did in mytestbranch and you don't want to use any of those changes, you don't have to do much, just switch to master and delete the branch:

```
git checkout master
git branch -D mytestbranch
```

If you want to merge all the changes you made in mytestbranch just do merge:

```
git checkout master
git merge mytestbranch
git branch -d mytestbranch
```

The difference between `git branch -D` and `git branch -d` is that the former can delete branches that have not been fully merged into HEAD.